# Google Places API response structure changed - Id field removed from predictions

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

In the below API results:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=bangalore&language=&components=country%3AIN&radius=3200&location=None%2CNone&types=%28regions%29&sensor=false&key=

Predictions results does not have id field in some cases.

Like description: "Bangalore South, Karnataka, India" does not have id.

Is this change in response structure expected?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results as you can see `id` is not part of the list. So it might be included, or not, I suppose. What do you want to do with that ID anyway? Most probably you should be looking at the `place_id` field.

Comment: I was using a python library which used id field in sending the response.
This library code started breaking, anyways I have raised an issue:
https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places/issues/126

Comment: I've tried the query above and it return an id for each, the id for "Bangalore South, Karnataka, India" that I got was `28de65fa412f4f1063cde94d9b6268f5e77e08b1`, I also checked your URL request and see that parameters like `language` and `location` have empty or invalid values, please note that this will be disregarded by the API by default.

Comment: @ShawnDomingo Seems like they have added id field again

Comment: @kapilmatani will update this thread in a few days with regards to this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also mentioned in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050526/google-map-places-service-returns-both-id-and-place-id-for-each-place-can-i-use/57089270#57089270), the **`id`** field has been deprecated as of June 2014 so it is not guaranteed that this field will always be returned. In replacement, you'll need to use the **`"place_id"`** field moving forward which uniquely identifies a place.

This has also been answered in Google's Public Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134893143